# Overwrite method in Ruby module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spina-cms

In Spina there is an class [Account](https://github.com/SpinaCMS/Spina/blob/master/app/models/spina/account.rb)

In which is called method:

```rb
serialized_attr_accessor :google_analytics, :google_site_verification, :facebook, :twitter, :instagram, :youtube, :linkedin, :google_plus, :theme
```

I have created an Module **Spina** with class **Account** in my */app/models/spina* directory, with absolutely the same code as in gem's account model, the only line which was changed, was:

```rb
serialized_attr_accessor :google_analytics, :google_site_verification, :facebook, :twitter, :instagram, :youtube, :linkedin, :twitch, :github, :theme
```

(basically added 2 more attributes)

I'm more than sure, that it is not correct approach and its lack of knowledge how the thinks work in Rails. Would be glad for the information, what would be the right solution/approach here.

P.S. New to Ruby and Rails, so please be super strict in answer.

**Update 12.07.20-1**
I created a monkey patch:

~/app/models/spina/account.rb

```rb
module Spina
  class Account < ApplicationRecord
    # here putted all code from [Account](https://github.com/SpinaCMS/Spina/blob/master/app/models/spina/account.rb)
  end
end
```

Comment: You created a "module spina with class account"? What does this mean? Can you show the definition?

Comment: Added update **Update 12.07.20-1**, cause formatting in comments is awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not used Spina myself and do not know the project.

This is not so much a Rails question as it is about the gem and how its authors envisioned it being customized.

From looking at the code of the gem [here](https://github.com/SpinaCMS/Spina/blob/8b7d163c3d617f6e5604244dcf32aadc58bfe510/app/models/spina/account.rb) (lines 16-29) it appears that `serialized_attr_accessor` is a class method of `Spina::Account` that goes over each argument provided and adds getter and setter methods dynamically.

Generally, you are right that in Rails you could add a file `app/models/spina/account.rb` and re-open the class. However, it does not cancel the definition of the class in other files. Therefore, the original `serialized_attr_accessor` call is still called - you cannot ignore it in this particular case.

As long as you are looking to add attributes and not remove any, you could have the following code executed and it should have the desired behavior. You can put this code in an an initializer (e.g. under `config/initializers/spina.rb` - all files under `config/initializers` are run alphabetically as part of the Rails boot process):

```rb
Spina::Account.serialized_attr_accessor :twitch, :github
```

However, while this fix might work for you today, if Spina's authors didn't specify that this extendability is supported as part of the gem's interface then you are running the risk that tomorrow (more precisely - in the next release of Spina) it might break. It could very well be that the authors never intended `serialized_attr_accessor` to be public, and might rename / remove / change its behavior in the next version - breaking your app.

Generally speaking, opening classes (called "monkey patching") and calling non-public methods (or unintended interfaces) is a practice that should be used sparingly, even if it can be done in Ruby, since you are coupling your code with the gem's implementation.

One additional thing to note here for this "fix". Those two attributes you added are not persistent in the database. They are only stored in memory. I am not sure whether any of the other fields persist, as I am not familiar with the gem. But if you need them to be persistent, you will have to add a migration in Rails. You could create a migration to modify the `spina_accounts` table, but this sounds like a bad idea as it strongly couples your application with their implementation. You could also consider creating your own `accounts` table that extends the Spina account by referencing an account record (e.g. `spina_account_id`) and add the extra fields that you need.

Either way, I suggest to open an issue on the gem's github page and ask whether they officially support the ability to customize the attributes of an account.

Comment: This is not a working solution, but this answer given me an direction in which I should move to resolve an issue and also given additional information about Rails stuff.

So, marking as "Accepted", cause as already mentioned, it's not so much about Rails as about the gem.

Huge thanks @AmitA for your response.